# Глагол "сторговать" в современном языке

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов, заимствования

> **СТОРГОВАТЬ**, сторгую, сторгуешь *(прост.)*. совер. к торговать во 2 знач. *«Он сторговал первый встречный угол и через час переехал».*
>   Достоевский.

Толковый словарь Ушакова.

---

> **СТОРГОВАТЬ** — что за что, обоюдно условиться, согласиться в цене, поладить, сойтись. Один сторговал, другой запродал. Сторговал не
>   купил, еще не покончил дела.

[Толковый словарь Даля](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/359958)

---

У меня:

> Бедный продавец второй раз обречённо проходил в раскалённой тишине
>   мимо наших столиков, когда я его окликнула, и мы начали играть в
>   любимую всеми восточными народами игру – **начали торговаться. Мы так
>   нередко развлекаемся, на спор сторговывая всякую ерунду**, из чистого
>   азарта. И **нам нередко идут на большие уступки**. Я уже приноровились. И
>   сейчас устроила из покупки целое шоу. Показательное выступление. **Я
>   сторговала пять таких волшебных кубиков всего за пять евро**, хотя
>   изначально пять стоил каждый из них. Процесс происходил долго и
>   обстоятельно, “с оттяжечкой”, с неожиданными прекращениями торгов, **с
>   немыслимыми расстройствами то одной, то другой стороны**, и с уходами, и
>   с **комбэками**, и с укорами, и со счастливыми примирениями перед
>   очередным раундом. Зрелище это заинтересовало всех чрезвычайно. В
>   особо напряжённые моменты я получала даже восторженные выкрики из
>   “зрительного зала”. За столиками возникло оживление. И оно усилилось ещё
>   больше, когда каждой паре досталось по сувениру.

---

[Что такое комбэк](http://teenslang.su/content/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%8D%D0%BA) и допустимо ли (по причине официальной незафиксированности) писать его через "о"?

Пожалуйста, откликнитесь на выделенное болдом, сумлеваюсь я.

Заметите ошибки - кричите!

Comment: Как-то этот *аффтар* мне все меньше и меньше нравится... (Ой, не по делу выступаю, сейчас забанят...)

Comment: А мне понравилось! А по поводу "комбэка"... Некоторыми словарями это слово фиксируется — с написаниями "камбэк", "камбек"... Посмотрите здесь: https://www.google.ru/search?tbm=bks&hl=ru&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%8D%D0%BA%22+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C

Comment: А по поводу СТОРГОВАТЬ в современном языке см. здесь: http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F1%F2%EE%F0%E3%EE%E2%E0%F2%FC&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=

Comment: И здесь: http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/plot.xml?smoothing=3&stat=gr_created_&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F1%F2%EE%F0%E3%EE%E2%E0%F2%FC&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка - в слове приноровил**а**сь. Первое предложение похоже на подстрочный перевод с английского. По-русски правильнее "**когда** продавец проходил, я его окликнула". Вместо "сторговать" лучше "**вы**торговать/выторговывать", тем более, что речь идёт о достижении выгодных условий торга. "Камбэк" (если в буквальном значении возвращения это слово уместно - обычно это привязанная к фиксированным контекстам идиома) нет оснований транскрибировать через "о" - это не имя собственное (бывают и противоположные несуразные крайности типа "камеди" - по североамериканскому варианту произношения слова comedy).

Answer (score 1):

1)  Из словаря Кузнецова: ТОРГОВАТЬ 4. (св. сторговать). что. **Разг.** Собираясь купить что-л., прицениваться, договариваться о цене.

Но плохо, что слово **повторяется**. Можно так: ***Мне досталось*** пять таких волшебных кубиков всего за пять евро...

2) Слово ***начали*** тоже повторяется, можно: ***стали торговаться***.