# "С немыслимыми расстройствами то одной, то другой стороны..."?

Tags: выбор-слов

Я уже задавала вопрос, где была эта фраза (часть), и было два ответа, и ноль реакции на мой болд...

([Глагол “сторговать” в современном языке](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448830/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5))

Речь о купле-продаже:

> Процесс происходил долго и обстоятельно, «с оттяжечкой», с
>   неожиданными прекращениями торгов, **с немыслимыми расстройствами то с
>   одной, то с другой стороны**, и с уходами, и с камбэками, и с укорами,
>   и со счастливыми примирениями перед очередным раундом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Процесс происходил долго и обстоятельно, **с оттяжечкой,** с неожиданными прекращениями торгов, **с немыслимыми (= чрезвычайными)  расстройствами (= огорчениями)** то с одной, то с другой стороны, и с уходами, и **с камбэками,** и с укорами, и со счастливыми примирениями перед очередным раундом.*

**Всё чудненько, ничего менять не надо.** ***Немыслимые расстройства*** – это чрезвычайные огорчения. Значение узнаваемое, а сочетание очень характерно для авторского стиля (чувствуется новизна и ироничность слога).

**Перечисления очень хороши** (двоеточия не надо), только **кавычки** хотелось бы убрать (переносное значение указано в словаре).

**Значения слов:**

1) **НЕМЫСЛИМЫЙ,**   2. Исключительный, чрезвычайный (по степени проявления, какого-л. качества, свойства).

2) ОТТЯЖКА 2. **Намеренное замедление, промедление в исполнении чего-нибудь, проволочка (разг.). Оттяжка в решении вопроса.** 
 https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/915958

В таком виде он и явился перед хорошенькой Сельмой Нагель: грудь колесом, плечи разведены, походка **с оттяжечкой,** в протянутой руке — пачка сигарет. [Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Град обреченный (1972)]

3) **КАМБЭК** [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/камбэк](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%8D%D0%BA)

За два последующих года Кэтти устала от моих исчезновений на недели и месяцы и звонков ...как ни в чём не бывало **после камбэка** из периодически засасывавшей меня чёрной дыры.

Answer (score 1):

Стилевые особенности автора позволяют принять и такой пассаж.

Мы тут видали и похлеще... )

Comment: Всё похлещее я убрала, неправда ваша! Думай над пассажем, плиз! Аккаунт платный, где править можно! Не дай книжке - а значит, мне - осрамиться пред людьми! Ааа!!!

Answer (score 1):

**расстройство** (в толковых словарях):
[Ожегов] 6) плохое настроение, утрата душевного равновесия. *Он сегодня в расстройстве*;
[Ефремова] 5) *перен.* Потеря душевного спокойствия, равновесия.

Так что очень даже "лепится".
А вот после "оттяжечкой" мне видится двоеточие. Нет?
(*Процесс происходил долго и обстоятельно, «с оттяжечкой»**:** с неожиданными прекращениями торгов, с немыслимыми расстройствами...*)